# 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' not found when Archiving in Xcode (from Worklight)

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode6

I'm suffering this error message when trying to Archive my app prior to submission to the App Store.

The full error is:

> In file included from /Users/Kevin/Documents/workspace/SongLink2/apps/SLPhone/iphone/native/Classes/CDVMainViewController.m:14:
>   In file included from Classes/CDVMainViewController.h:15:
>   /Users/Kevin/Documents/workspace/SongLink2/apps/SLPhone/iphone/native/WorklightSDK/include/MainViewController.h:34:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found
>
> ```
> #import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
>         ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

I'm using Worklight 6.2 to generate the project having added both Android and iPhone environments). I then switch to Xcode 6 to Run my app. This is successful for Run but fails when I Product->Archive with the error.

I've recently upgraded everything to:

- IBM Worklight Studio 6.2.0.00-20140915-1601
- Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317)

... but with no success.

I've tried:

- [Changing Header>Search Paths:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883471/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-not-found-when-archiving-for-distribution) but this had no effect. This also suggest reinstalling Cordova but I'm unsure how to do this in a Worklight environment.
- [Perform Product->Clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios) with no effect. This discussion also suggested running ./update_cordova_subproject /path/to/your/project but I don't know where Worklight installed cordova to try it.
- Many discussions suggest Xcode->Preferences->Locations->Advanced and make sure it's set to Unique... but I'm already set to this value.
- [similar:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728714/cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-run-in-xcode-terminal) but this didn't seem to get resolved

Please help me on my last step to app store submission!

Comment: Duh! Turns out I had a spurious " (double quote) in my Header Search Path. Sorry to waste everyones time.

Comment: Kevin Gurden, would you mind to either remove the question or provide your answer below so that others could benefit from it?

Comment: This is a genuine problem (don't know why someone downvoted the question) which was certainly affecting me. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at the Header Search Path(s) I noticed I'd introduced an extra double quote which was causing Xcode some confusion! Once I removed that it worked fine. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem and the solution was a classic XCode mystery incantation to add to your search path:

```
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"
```

Found on this website:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-in-xcode-7-1-beta/32232/4

Comment: and in some cordova configurations you need to set **Enable Bitcode** to **No**

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in terminal

```
cordova platform update ios
```

if this didnt work try running

```
ionic capacitor update
```

for me second one worked